# Не меняется цвет кнопки

Tags: javascript

Значение dddd меняется при нажатии на кнопку

```js
        if(dddd>=75){
        wib3.value="✔";
        wib3.style.backgroundColor="MediumSpringGreen";
}
 
        if(dddd<=70){ 
        wib3.value="✘";
        wib6.value="✘";
        wib6.style.backgroundColor="Crimson";
        wib3.style.backgroundColor="Crimson";
        }
```

```html
<input id="wib3" class="wi" type="submit" onclick="wibr3()" value="✘">
```

Comment: 1. Что такое `dddd`? 2. Где обьект `wib6`?

Comment: Значение dddd не меняется при нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вам нужно хотя бы объявить переменные и функцию. Не понятно что вы хотите получить, в вашем коде нет ничего, что могло бы работать.

Вот пример, как я понял:

Вы получаете значение  переменной dddd (в данном случае из поля ввода), кликаете на кнопку и цвет кнопки и ее value изменяется в зависимости от содержимого

```js
var wib3 = document.getElementById("wib3");
var wib = document.getElementById("wib");

wib3.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var dddd = document.getElementById("wib").value;

  if (dddd >= 75) {
    wib3.value = "✔";
    wib3.style.backgroundColor = "MediumSpringGreen";
  } else {

    if (dddd <= 70) {
      wib3.value = "✘";
      wib3.style.backgroundColor = "Crimson";
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<input id="wib" class="wi" type="text" value="" placeholder = "введите значение">
<input id="wib3" class="wi" type="submit" value="✘">
```